# Each section in INI should be separated with blank line

Tags: c#, ini

I am using `WritePrivateProfileString` kernal32 function to write into INI file.

But when ever I write into INI file the section will be like below only,

```
[Section1]
Key1 = value1
key2 = value2
[Section2]
Key1 = value1
key2 = value2
```

Now I am looking for solution to separate section as below

```
[Section1]
Key1 = value1
key2 = value2

[Section2]
Key1 = value1
key2 = value2
```

I am just writing few keys to existing INI file so I dont want to use any third party code.
and also opening existing file in text mode and put blank line explicitly is not recommended in my case.

Please advise if there any kernel32 function to put/write section such a way, or any standard way to do the same.

It should be intelligent enough to consider blank line if already exists.

Comment: Why in the world would you care about this? INI files aren't designed to be beautiful, they're designed to be practical.

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved this by using `Environment.NewLine` appended with last value of each section. See following code:

INI Class `INIClass.cs`:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "WritePrivateProfileString", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern long WriteValueA(string section, string key, string val, string filePath);

public void IniWriteValue(string Section, string Key, string Value)
    {
        WriteValueA(Section, Key, Value, this.path);
    }
```

Now for section when I call `IniWriteValue`.

```
INIClass objINI = new INIClass();
objINI.IniWriteValue("Section1", "Key1", Value1 );
objINI.IniWriteValue("Section1", "Key2", Value2 + Environment.NewLine);

objINI.IniWriteValue("Section2", "Key1", Value1 );
```

Result will be like this:

```
[Section1]
Key1 = Value1
Key2 = Value2

[Section2]
Key1 = Value1
```

**NOTE**: physical *path* of INI file is provided at class level.

Comment: *"It should be intelligent enough to consider blank line if already exists."* Does your solution meet this criteria?

Comment: NO. That is why I mentioned "how I achieved this". May be this will be helpful for the poster.

Comment: Hi @HassanNisar: Thanks but it does not helps me, Adding newline will add extra blank lines on every run, and in my case i never know the last key that I will be writing because it is based on data available at run time. 
I need something which should exactly identify section & add extra line after each section if not exists. ( may be manual C# coding i need to do)

Comment: Have you checked `GetPrivateProfileSection()`? This function `retrieves all the keys and values for the specified section of an initialization file.` But still you need to traverse through all sections. This  link http://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/using-getprivateprofilesection-in-c/ may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've created an IniParser library completely in c# (MIT license)

https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser

Also available as a NuGet package

It's [heavily configurable](https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser/wiki/Configuring-parser-behavior); the default behaviour appends a line between sections as you asked, but if you don like it, you can [implement your own formatter](https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser/blob/master/src/IniFileParser/Model/Formatting) to format the data for your needs. Formatters are a recent feature, feel free to give feedback if you end up using it :).

As an example, to write data in runtime in the format of your example you just need to do

```
var data = new IniData();
data["Section1"]["Key1"] = value1;
data["Section1"]["Key2"] = value2;
data["Section2"]["Key1"] = value1;
data["Section2"]["Key2"] = value2;

// Now you can get the ini data as an string
var str = data.ToString();

// or persists it to a file
var fileIniData = new FileIniDataParser();
fileIniData.WriteFile("path/to/file.ini", data);
```

I hope it can be of help to you.